# return early vs if in ruby code

Tags: ruby, coding-style, guard-clause

I see two styles of writing the same thing:

```
def find_nest(animal)
  return unless animal.bird?
  GPS.find_nest(animal.do_crazy_stuff)
end
```

vs

```
def find_nest(animal)
  if animal.bird?
     GPS.find_nest(animal.do_crazy_stuff)
  end
end
```

Which one is more correct/preferable/following-best-practises? Or it does not matter?

Comment: I'd write `GPS.find_nest(animal.do_crazy_stuff) if animal.bird?`

Comment: @Stefan I always come up with terrible examples for questions :P

Comment: @Stefan: I find modifier conditionals confusing in case of expressions where value matters. Only use them on "statements" and only if the primary expression is not too long (or else it'd push the modifier out of sight)

Comment: @FilipBartuzi since your question is tagged _oop_ – of course it would be preferable to have a `Bird` class (descendant of `Animal`) and implement `Bird#find_nest` without arguments as `def find_nest; GPS.find_nest(do_crazy_stuff); end`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per [Ruby style guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-nested-conditionals),

> Prefer a guard clause when you can assert invalid data. A guard clause
> is a conditional statement at the top of a function that bails out as
> soon as it can.
>
> ```
> # bad
> def compute_thing(thing)
>   if thing[:foo]
>     update_with_bar(thing)
>     if thing[:foo][:bar]
>       partial_compute(thing)
>     else
>       re_compute(thing)
>     end
>   end
> end
>
> # good
> def compute_thing(thing)
>   return unless thing[:foo]
>   update_with_bar(thing[:foo])
>   return re_compute(thing) unless thing[:foo][:bar]
>   partial_compute(thing)
> end
> ```

Answer (score 6):

It is obviously a matter of personal preference. But I prefer the early return. Not only does it make code "flatter" and easier to read, it also scales well with the number of checks. For example:

```
  def create_terms_of_service_notification
    return if Rails.env.test?
    return if current_user.accepted_tos?
    # imagine 5 more checks here. 
    # Now imagine them as a mess of nested ifs.

    # create the notification
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This :}

```
def find_nest(animal)
  GPS.find_nest(animal.do_crazy_stuff) if animal.bird?
end
```